# Best way to store settings and reports on server

Tags: sql, database, settings

Say I have a lot of accounts. Each account will have settings associated with it. Is it best to store these settings in an SQL database, with each setting being a column, and link a row to an account?

Then say I have a report with entries that may not be filled out. Is the best approach for this the same, and have a lot of empty cells?

Thanks!

FWIW: I'm using Python, and I don't have to use SQL if there are better options.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the approach of using one row per account to store settings.

The temptation might be use the [EAV model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) but that could lead you to the pitfall of creating a system-within-a-system.

Concerning your report, consider creating a separate table to hold the report settings. Assuming you'll have more than one report type, make a separate row for each combination report type and user account.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to use SQL, will you consider using Mongo ?

it can fit you well since it's a document oriented, meaning each "row" can have different setting with no real problem

Comment: I didn't have an objection to SQL.

Comment: Mongo will suit you better for what you want

Comment: Actually, it looks really good—especially as my client software uses JSON for the communication. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, quickly—if you know the answer—I just planned out a document. It has like 50 lines, and many nested arrays. I like the idea of every account having its own document, but it does look to be a large file. Is this an issue for MongoDB, or is it sort of what it was designed for? Thanks!

Comment: Mongo can handle 50 lines easily , nested array are not a problem since things are store in JSON like.Mongo design to save documents so I would try it out